# Create alphabetical list with links

Tags: python, django

I have a list of people (something like, in my model:

```
surname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I'd like to output a table for each starting letter of a surname. So, for example (in the template):

```
<table class='table'>
{% for author in content %}
<tr>
    {% if author.surname|first == "A" %}
    <td>{{ author.surname }}</td>
    {% endif %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

The above code works. Nevertheless, is it possible to somewhat automate the above code instead of building as many 'ifs' (and templates) as the letters of the alphabet? I'd like something like A B C D E etc... with links on each letter, and when clicking on one letter it outputs a table for the surnames starting with A B C D E etc...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How about looping over another list which has all the alphabets and comparing the first letter with that?

Comment: how you will get the letter on which the user clicked ? Suppose 'S' ? i am guessing in view through url query parameter ?

Comment: Instead of sorting in the tempate, it would be easier if you sort the list in the view first and then pass it to the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

```
{% regroup content by surname.0 as authors %}
<ul>
    {% for author in authors %}
    <li>{{ author.grouper }}
        <ul>
        {% for item in author.list %}
            <li>{{ item.get_surname}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This will regroup your content by the first character of surname, the `grouper` then becomes the first letter, whilst the `list` is the authors with that letter

The ordering the grouping will use is dependant on the content's order, therefore you may need to order the content by surname first before passing into your template.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I cannot vote your answer yet (need to earn 15 reputation first).

Anyway, that's what I did:

    <br />
{% regroup content by surname.0 as authors %}
<ul>
    {% for author in authors %}
    <li><a name="{{ author.grouper|first }}">{{ author.grouper }}</a>
        <ul>
        {% for item in author.list %}
            <li><a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.surname }}, {{ item.firstname }} {{ item.extrainfo }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>    

so that each author_grouper letter has its own anchor to which I can link with a href.

Comment: @HBMCS - Glad it worked for you, you don't need to upvote an answer, although if you wish, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking inside the 'tick'/'check' outline below the voting icons

Comment: I don't even have the voting icons, as far as I can see!

Comment: @HBMCS - Ah sorry, its on the left below the vote score! See [this explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more info :)